# Is there a way to search github issues with linked pull requests?

Tags: github, github-search

I want to know how to filter issues only with linked pull requests. I've been trying to use the `linked-pull-request` but it needs a PR number. But I want to filter all issues with pull request

Answer (score 2):

Add `linked:pr` to the end of the search query.